# Storybook - Include css from assets folder return "Refused to include..." error

Tags: css, mime, storybook

I'm including Font Awesome inside my Storybook Stencil project.
This is my project structure

```
|-> src
    |-> assets
        |-> fontawesome
            |-> css
                |-> all.css
|-> .storybook
    |-> manager-head.html
    |-> preview-head.html
```

In order to make font awesome work inside storybook, as I read in the doc, I need to include inside  **manager-head** and **preview-head** this reference

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="../src/assets/fontawesome/css/all.css"
/>
```

But when I start storybook, I have this problem:
[image]
[image]

The full error is:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:6007/src/assets/fontawesome/css/all.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

I don't know why the error said **MIME type ('text/html')**, because I wrote **type="text/css"**
The path it's correct but and I don't know why I have this error.

Answer (score 4):

**Deprecated**
[image]

You should specify the directory where static files will be loaded from (e.g. your css files) in the package.json:

[image]

You can read more about the CLI options [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/cli-options/).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but I have to admit I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. What syntax would you use to add it to the package.json file?

Comment: Hello @LeslieP. I was talking about storybook's -s option where you can define a directory where you can put your static files (e.g. your css files), but it had been depracated as per documentation: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/cli-options#static-dir-deprecation